# pass data using alpine js @click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, onclick, alpine.js

I have a link with alpinejs `@click event`

```
<a class="parent post_no" data-value="<?php echo $total_posts_parent ?>" @click="filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)"><?= esc_html( $category->name); echo " ". "(" .$total_posts_parent . ")" ?></a>
```

how can I add the Var `$total_posts_parent` to the @click and have it received in my alpine function?

**Function**

Want the on @click `$total_posts_parent` to populate `total`

```
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
posts: "",
limit: 6,
category: 0,
post_type_js: post_id,
showDefault: true,
showFiltered: false,
offset: 0,
total: 0, // want to get the value from the varible here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$el.dataset.value` you can access to the *data-value* value of the current element, you can use it in the *@click* event or directly in the *filterPosts()* method:

```js
@click="total += parseInt($el.dataset.value) || 0; filterPosts(<?= $category->term_id; ?>)">
```

or:

```js
@click="filterPosts($el.dataset.value, <?= $category->term_id; ?>)">

.....

<script>

Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({

   ......

   filterPosts: function (theValue, termId) {

       this.total += parseInt(theValue) || 0;
       
       .....
   }

</script>
```

or:

```js
Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({

   ......
    
    total: 0,

    filterPosts: function ($someData) {

        this.total += parseInt(this.$el.dataset.value) || 0;

    }
```

Comment: If i use the second example how do I get this into my alpin function ?

Comment: First one for the win, thank you

Comment: hmm did work at least now NaN

Comment: I've edited the answer adding an example for the second option. Moreover, if you foresee to assign also a non numerical value to *data-value*, you can use `parseInt(this.$el.dataset.value) || 0` to manage NaN values